# Can emails be received to a deleted Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

I deleted my Gmail account completely. After a few days I restored it. All of my emails were still intact.

My question is: while the account was still in "delete status" and not active, would someone still be able to send me an email? Or, would they have gotten a message letting them know that the Gmail account was not active and the mail returned to them?

Answer (score 3):

In such a case, they would receive an e-mail saying "Message Delivery Failed. The Specified account does not exists" or something extremely similar to that.